# Pointer x Reference to a Class in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pointers, dereference

Is there any advantage in using Pointer instead Reference to classes?
for example:

```
TMyClass = class(TObject);

procedure Method;
var
    pmc : ^TMyClass;
    //instead of
    mc : TMyClass;       
begin
   pmc := @ObjectMyClass;
   //instead of
   mc := ObjectMyClass;

   if pmc.Enabled then
      blablabla;
   //instead of
   if mc.Enabled then 
     blebleble;           
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All classes in Delphi are passed/used by reference, so adding another level of indirection doesn't add anything.

This does not hold for records, which are always passed/used by value. One can use these by reference by declaring a pointer type and pass these to functions by using the pointer type or the var keyword (which handles the pointer function argument mess for you).

(Ctrl+F for "class")
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types

In case you're familiar with C/C++, ^TMyClass is equivalent to:

```
**MyClass
```

This is useful in some cases like when you want to edit a pointer using a function by passing a pointer to the pointer to that function, but I doubt these constructions are possible using Delphi.

Comment: So it's only usefull for large arrays or records?

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: it's useful for any data you want to edit using functions, so yes.

Comment: Extra layer of of indirection meams you have to have two variables when one will do. Very bad idea.

Comment: Double indirect pointers are typically used to resolve forward references when streaming in object trees from a file. You basically store a list of the memory addresses of variables or fields which need to be updated to point to the desired object after the target object is loaded. These constructions are quite possible using Delphi, but definitely not the sort of thing an application developer would ever need to do. It's a tool for low-level plumbers, not application devs.